# Unable to setup JFrog Artifactory Pro (Trial) without reverse proxy ('Repository Path' Docker Access Method) on AWS Kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I have installed JFrog Artifactory Pro Trial(v5.8.3) on Kubernetes cluster on AWS using the official Helm chart:

```
helm install --name artifactory stable/artifactory
```

I have mapped the ELB launched by the Artifactory chart to Route53 DNS entry jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com

I'm able to access the Jfrog application on the URL: [jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com](http://jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com/)

Now, I want to push Docker images from my local machine to Artifactory. I have set up Docker repository on Artifactory and want to expose it without using a reverse proxy. I have chosen 'Repository Path' as the Docker Access Method in the HTTP Settings Configuration:

[image]

I have chosen 'Embedded Tomcat' in the reverse proxy settings:

[image]

The HTTP Settings in the Advanced settings page of docker, docker-local and docker-remote are auto-populated like this:

[image]

I'm getting a 200 response on the following URL: http://jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com/artifactory/api/docker/docker/v2

However, I'm getting 404 response on the following URL: http://jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com/v2/

[image]

On my local machine, I have added jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com to the insecure registries by editing the /etc/docker/daemon.json:

[image]

After reloading the Docker daemon, I can see the URL added to the insecure registries:

[image]

I have also enabled anonymous access to the registry. But when I try to pull an image or login to the directory, I get 500 Internal Server error:
[image]

Please help with any pointers or any obvious mistakes I maybe doing.

Answer (score 1):

- When adding jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com, you also need to specify the port Artifactory is running on. e.g. **jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com:8081**
  Then, reload the Docker daemon.

  - Then, when you try to login through the Docker client, you should run the following:
    **docker login -u {USER_NAME} -p {USER_PASSWORD} jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com:8081**
  - To pull an image, you need to specify the Docker virtual repo name as part of the request. If you're using a virtual repository named docker-virtual, you should run the following: 
    **docker pull jfrogartifactory.qdatalabs.com:8081/docker-virtual/hello-world**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Embedded Tomcat works only on HTTP. Since I was running Artifactory behind an HTTPS Load Balancer on AWS, all HTTP traffic was getting converted to HTTPS before reaching Artifactory. Hence Docker daemon wasn't able to properly authenticate with Artifactory. I solved the issue by configuring an NGINX reverse proxy